# Swift. Вытягиваю картинки в ячейки через api. Все билдится, нннно вместо картинок - пусто. Возвращается nil. Пол дня сижу не могу понять!

Tags: ios, swift, изображения

Swift. Я новичок еще. Вытягиваю картинки в ячейки через api. Все отлично билдится, нннно вместо картинок - пусто. Возвращается nil. Пол дня сижу не могу понять!!

Если этот ответ есть где-то, прошу простить, и если не сложно дать ссылку, благодарю.

Ссылка api - https://swiftbook.ru//wp-content/uploads/api/api_courses

Где туплю подскажите?

**Заранее очень благодарен за помощь и разъяснения !!!**

```
import UIKit

class CourseCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var courseImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var courseNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberOfLessons: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberOfTests: UILabel!
    
    func configure(with course: Course) {
        
        courseNameLabel.text = course.name
        numberOfLessons.text = "Number of lessons \(course.number_of_lessons ?? 0)"
        numberOfTests.text = "Number of tests \(course.number_of_tests ?? 0)"
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
            guard let stringUrl = course.imageUrl,
                  let imageURL = URL(string: stringUrl),
                  let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }      
   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда я с включенным VPN забилдил очередной раз, и все картинки погрузились. Все потому что в Украине залакированы сейчас все .ru домены, а url api как раз с .ru

Надо было видеть мои глаза

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь в том, что вы используете не ту очередь для работы с UI (`global`), в то время как нужно использовать `main`, исправление:

```
    func configure(with course: Course) {
        
        courseNameLabel.text = course.name
        numberOfLessons.text = "Number of lessons \(course.number_of_lessons ?? 0)"
        numberOfTests.text = "Number of tests \(course.number_of_tests ?? 0)"
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            guard let stringUrl = course.imageUrl,
                  let imageURL = URL(string: stringUrl),
                  let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            else {
                return
            }
            
            self.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну это сделано мною, как я понял, потому что мы можем столкнуться с оч большим кол-вом данных, и мы откроем экран только после того как загрузятся все картинки, когда отработает segue, то отправил это все в глобальный поток. Есть я не прав, разъясните

Comment: И знаете в чем была проблема?!))) Ошалеть. Когда я случайно запустил с включенным VPN, то все загрузилось) Все потому что я в Украине,  а у нас почти все домены .ru заблочены, а url api как раз ru

Comment: @V777 у вас заработал ваш вариант с `global` или мой?

Comment: С global. Но за ваш ответ большое спасибо! Он тоже рабочий уверен